# how to sign a string with a private key

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a system that an supposed to give my partner a public key to decry-pt the text. What I want is how to sign that text using my private key. This is how am doing it but it has failed.

```
require 'openssl'
    require 'base64'
    require 'digest/sha1'

    @date = Date.today.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
    text_to_sign = "#{@order.phone_no}" + "#{@order.name}" + "#{@order.pay_type}" + "#{@order.pay_type}" + "1" + "MABIRA" + "81W30DI846" + "#{@date}" + "PULL" + "1" + "#{@cart.total_price}" + "#{@order.phone_no}" + ""        

    cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new 'aes-256-cbc'
    cipher.encrypt
    cipher.key = cipher.random_key
    cipher.iv = cipher.random_iv

    encrypted = cipher.update(text_to_sign) + cipher.final
    private_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read('Private.key'), password)
    ciphertext = private_key.private_encrypt(encrypted)
    ciphertext.encoding
    signed_text = Base64.encode64(ciphertext).gsub("\n", '')
    puts signed_text
    signed_text
```

Comment: What is not working for you?

Comment: when i send this is how the base64 encoded string looks like RBAMnmyLhQKKziRS43CEJzk3GI8d6BwDFQuXkMl62lGVNEY5Z8rFNW/F4o9IbTpfhYYlPqIEh8Zq
E6FkXEpC3t544CCwuCD+T5EnQ/SMW17qL1jdwl/uhxm96wDV2788ZjLT5g1SptX5Q6JHRNkhtUUrWzAX
WHXUzIJhC32u/lU=

Comment: that is how the signed string looks like in base64 but I don't know where the / are coming from